# Running functions on a timer while allowing mouse actions

Tags: java, timer, jform

so I am working on a little hobby project, and basically I want to be able to click a button and have a function run every 30 seconds, but also be able to click another button and have it cancel the previous timer and start a new one which will run a different function.

For example:

```
btnGeneral.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0){
            try{
                lblCategory.setIcon(yellowBanner);
                lblCategory.setText("General");
                getGeneral();
            }
            catch(IOException | InterruptedException e){

            }
        }
    });
```

I want to run the function getGeneral() every 30 seconds after the button is pressed.

But if another button is pressed I want it to run a different function on the 30 second timer instead.

Is this possible? and if so, is it also possible to have this run from start up without holding up the paint process?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Take on look at javax.swing.Timer for details and concurrency in swing for more info

Comment: That seemed to solve my problem, thank you. It has slowed it down a little though, so I may have to look into putting them into the background threads